# EvictingQueue in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, collections

I need a collection that:

- has a fixed size
- is mutable
- will re-index elements once a new element is added, removing the oldest element (like a shift register)

I think Guava's [`EvictingQueue`](https://guava.dev/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html) and Apache Commons [`CircularFifoQueue`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) is what I need.

However, I am on Android, and was hoping Kotlin already has something similar. But I did not find yet ;)

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin has [`ArrayDeque`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-deque/), which has simple methods for removing and adding elements to a list.

It doesn't have a limited capacity though.

Using a custom [Delegated property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html) is a fairly lightweight way to wrap an existing `ArrayDeque` so we can intercept calls and ensure the limit is maintained.

### `dequeLimiter`

The method `dequeLimiter` is based on the [`NotNullVar`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/34e57a45f2d4283be572137b4b497414b8833ee7/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/properties/Delegates.kt#L58) delegate.

Whenever the internal `deque` field is read or written, it calls `applyLimit()` and this removes any excess items.

```kotlin
import kotlin.properties.ReadWriteProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty


fun <E> dequeLimiter(limit: Int): ReadWriteProperty<Any?, ArrayDeque<E>> =
  object : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, ArrayDeque<E>> {

    private var deque: ArrayDeque<E> = ArrayDeque(limit)

    private fun applyLimit() {
      while (deque.size > limit) {
        val removed = deque.removeFirst()
        println("dequeLimiter removed $removed")
      }
    }

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): ArrayDeque<E> {
      applyLimit()
      return deque
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: ArrayDeque<E>) {
      this.deque = value
      applyLimit()
    }
  }
```

### Usage

The delegate is applied on any `ArrayDeque` with the `by` keyword (see [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html) for more info).

After this, the deque can be used as normal and will be automatically limited.

```kotlin
fun main() {

  // create a deque, and use our property delegate to intercept
  // invocations and limit the size to 3
  val limitedDeque: ArrayDeque<Int> by dequeLimiter(3)

  // try adding 5 elements
  (0..5).forEach {
    limitedDeque.add(it)
    println("limitedDeque: $limitedDeque")
  }
  /* output */
  // limitedDeque: [0]
  // limitedDeque: [0, 1]
  // limitedDeque: [0, 1, 2]
  // dequeLimiter removed 0
  // limitedDeque: [1, 2, 3]
  // dequeLimiter removed 1
  // limitedDeque: [2, 3, 4]
  // dequeLimiter removed 2
  // limitedDeque: [3, 4, 5]

  // try removing 5 elements
  repeat(5) {
    val removedLast = limitedDeque.removeLastOrNull()
    println("removedLast: $removedLast")
    println("limitedDeque: $limitedDeque")
  }
  /* output */
  // removedLast: 5
  // limitedDeque: [3, 4]
  // removedLast: 4
  // limitedDeque: [3]
  // removedLast: 3
  // limitedDeque: []
  // removedLast: null
  // limitedDeque: []
  // removedLast: null
  // limitedDeque: []

}
```

Comment: That's a nice idea 