# FIFO (Deque) with limited size

Tags: android, kotlin

How to make a FIFO in a kotlin with a limited size ?
Does Kotlin have collections of this type ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EvictingQueue in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63903335/evictingqueue-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class *LimitDeque* , override *fun push*

```
class LimitDeque<T>(private val limitSize: Int): ArrayDeque<T>() {
        override fun push(p0: T) {
            if (this.size >= limitSize) pollLast()
            super.push(p0)
        }
    }
```

Example:

```
val deque: Deque<Int> = LimitDeque(3)
deque.push(1)
deque.push(2)
deque.push(3)
deque.push(4)
deque.push(5)

deque.forEach(::print) //543
```

Comment: Got compile error when trying this implementation - 'ArrayDeque' type is final, so it cannot be inherited from.